# Using xlsx file to do load testing with Locust

Tags: python, api, xlsx, load-testing, locust

I wanna use xlsx file instead of a single data for post request in locust. How can i do this in "self.client.post" ?

Comment: Do you have any work?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easiest to export from excel to a csv file and then either read the csv using regular python code, or the wrapper provided by locust-plugins (see https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/csvreader_ex.py)